# How to force the Esri world imagery basemap to show the same seasonal imagery in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps

When I export a layout using Esri's world imagery basemap, the basemap is combining both winter (with snow) and summer imagery in the same map (see screenshot below, left-side of image is winter). It makes the map confusing to understand. This only happens at scales below 1:14 000, as far as I can figure out. Above this scale, the entire map shows summer imagery. I have cleared the cache for the basemap but this has not helped.

Is there any way to force the basemap to show the same season, ideally summer imagery?

[image]

Comment: It means imagery provider doesn't have higher resolution tiles for summer